# Need to index some variables in Zotero using Dublin Core

Tags: php, drupal-6

I want to index some variables from my site in Zotero using Dublin Core. I searched how to index these variables but didn't yet find a solution. Some of the variables are listed below.

1. Number of Pages
2. Series
3. Series Number
4. Number of Volumes
5. Place
6. Call Number
7. Series Title
8. Series Text
9. Journal Abbreviation
10. Episode Number
11. Running Time
12. Section
13. Report Number
14. Meeting Name
15. Guest
16. Program Title
17. Report Type

I am indexing the title like this: `<meta name="dc.title" content="lorem ipsum"/>`. Please tell me how to index the other variables.

Answer (score 0):

also asked and answered here: http://forums.zotero.org/discussion/23021/some-variables-need-to-index-in-zotero-using-dublian-core/#Item_4

The DC standard isn't rich enough to allow display and/or import of these types of fields. The best way to do this is to use a rich standard like MODS or Bibliontology RDF and serve it to Zotero via unAPI 
http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/exposing_metadata#using_an_open_standard_for_exposing_metadata